# Or comparison not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT: SOLVED WITH IF-ELSE STATEMENT**

In my 'if' statement, the or || comparison is not working. I previously got an answer from this website, with this string of code:

```
if(answers.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || answers2.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
```

However this does not work for my purposes (it sees if the userAnswer is in the array, while I want the statement to be true if the 3rd userAnswer matches with the 3rd answer in the array.)

Here is my code:

```
var answers = ["hello", "my name is sam", "are you healthy?", "what is your name?", "how much does it cost?", "excuse me", "i'm sorry", "yes, i understand", "no, i don't understand", "just wait please", "where is the toilet?"];

var answers2 = ["hello", "my name is sam", "how are you?", "what's your name?", "how much is it?", "excuse me", "sorry", "yes, all right", "no, i don't understand", "wait, please", "where's the toilet?"];

var totalYes = 0;
var ct = 0;

$("#submmit").click(function() {
    function checkAnswers() {
        var userAnswer = document.getElementById("b" + ct).value.toLowerCase();
        /**aforementioned if statement or comparison wannabe on next line**/
        if (userAnswer === answers[ct]) {
            totalYes++;
            $("#correcto").show();
        } else {
            $("#incorrecto").show();
            if (answers[ct] !== answers2[ct]) {
                alert("The correct answer is " + "'" + answers[ct] + "'" + " or " + "'" + answers2[ct] + "'");
            } else {
                alert("The correct answer is " + "'" + answers[ct] + "'");
            }
        }
    }
    checkAnswers();
    ct++;
});
```

Comment: Please do not "answer" your question by editing the question.  Write an answer (or pick an existing answer that helped)  and accept it.

Comment: Now that you have edited your question, what is the point in the `checkAnswers` function?

Answer (score 1):

did you try to put paranthesis around each side of the OR ?

```
if(( answers.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ) || (answers2.indexOf(userAnswer.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ) );
```

maybe this fixes it, i´m always not to sure about js but its definetly not an error